# Как организовать скачивание файла из WebView приложения?

Tags: webview, download, android-webview

Как мне организовать скачивание файла по прямой ссылке на сайте WebView приложения?
Может есть какие то готовые библиотеки?

Answer (score 0):

Вот мой пример кода:

```
mWebView.setDownloadListener(new DownloadListener() {
            @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
            @Override
            public void onDownloadStart(String url, String userAgent, String contentDisposition, String mimeType, long contentLength) {
                if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
                    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(getActivity(), android.Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                        DownloadManager.Request request = new DownloadManager.Request(Uri.parse(url));
                        request.setMimeType(mimeType);
                        String cookies = CookieManager.getInstance().getCookie(url);
                        request.addRequestHeader("cookie", cookies);
                        request.addRequestHeader("User-Agent", userAgent);
                        request.setDescription("Загрузка документа....");
                        request.setTitle(URLUtil.guessFileName(url, contentDisposition, mimeType));
                        request.allowScanningByMediaScanner();
                        request.setNotificationVisibility(DownloadManager.Request.VISIBILITY_VISIBLE_NOTIFY_COMPLETED);
                        request.setDestinationInExternalPublicDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS, URLUtil.guessFileName(url, contentDisposition, mimeType));
                        DownloadManager dm = (DownloadManager)getActivity().getSystemService(Context.DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);
                        dm.enqueue(request);
                        Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), "Документ загружен", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    } else {
                        Log.d("permission", "Разрешить сохранять файлы?");
                        String[] permissions = {Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE};
                        requestPermissions(permissions, 1);
                    }
                }
            }
        });
```

Comment: Спасибо большое!

Comment: Почему у меня подсвечивается request?

Comment: подтяни библиотеку